# Receiving error 'Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.SearchAPI' or one of its dependencies.'

Tags: iis-7.5

The full message is 'Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.SearchAPI' or one of its dependencies.  This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.'

After changing some application pools in IIs 7.5 from 2.0 to 4.0 and then back to 2.0 I now receive the above error message. I'm not sure what I need to do to switch the assembly from 4.0 to 2.0.

Thanks for the help!!

Gary

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell us what was your reasons for switching from .NET 4.0 to .NET 2.0.

There are major differences between these runtimes. You can load .NET 2.0 assembly in .NET 4.0 environment but it is not possible to do the other way. If you need to run your application in .NET 2.0 environment then the only option for you is to rebuild all assemblies using .NET 2.0 (or max. .NET 3.5 because the underlying CLR format is the same).

You can read more about .NET versions and compatibility [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bs2ecf4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to resolve a problem in Exchange. In the process of trying different things I switched the application pool fro 2.0 to 4.0. When I did that, if I understand it correctly, changes were made to web.config. It's also my understanding that when you switch back those changes are not reversed. The new result is I receive the above error when I go to remote.xxx.com.